# Resilience4j vs Sentinel

Tags: hystrix, sentinel, resilience4j

We are looking to replace Hystrix with Resilience4j or Sentinel. I am looking for advice on which one should be preferred. I have spent some time searching on google but could find any clear conclusion.
Both libraries have their own features. We want to primarily use it for circuit breaking.
Can anyone please guide me?